# Trying to implement a spin-lock via "lock xchg" assembly

Tags: c, att

Basically, I'm trying to run void spinlock_counter(int) in two threads and count ought to be 2000(parameter doesn't do anything I'm just too lazy). However I made a breakpoint in the critical zone i.e. "count++" and printed "flag", the flag is "GO" (the flag should be "BLOCK" if everything worked).
didn't get why this hadn't worked.

Thank you for your answers!

code:

```
int xchg(volatile int *addr, int newval){
    int result;
    asm volatile("lock xchg %0, %1"
    :"+m"(addr),
    "=a"(result)
    :"1"(newval)
    :"cc");
    return result;
}
#define GO 0
#define BLOCK 1
int flag = GO;

void lock(int *addr){
    int note = BLOCK;
    while(!xchg(addr, note));
}

void unlock_spin(int *addr){
    int note = GO;
    xchg(addr, note);
}

void spinlock_counter(int a){
    while(1) {
        lock(&flag);
        count++;
        unlock_spin(&flag);
        }
        printf("%d\n", count);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition in your while loop (in `lock()`) is backwards.

The consequence is that `lock()` effectively does nothing. If another thread already acquired the lock it won't spin at all, and if the lock was `GO` it'll spin once (setting the lock to `BLOCK` on the first iteration so that the spinning stops on the 2nd iteration).

I'd recommend writing code that describes your intent in a clearer/less confusing/less error prone way (and never relying on the value of true/false in C) so that these kinds of bugs are prevented. E.g.:

```
void lock(int *addr){
    int note = BLOCK;
    while(xchg(addr, note) != GO);
}
```

> However I made a breakpoint in the critical zone i.e. "count++" and printed "flag", the flag is "GO"

This is probably a separate bug (although the first bug can cause a different thread to unlock after your thread locks it wouldn't be easily reproducible). Specifically; nothing prevents the compiler from re-ordering your code and you'll want some kind of barrier to prevent the compiler transforming your code into the equivalent of `lock(&flag); unlock_spin(&flag);` then `count++;`. Changing the clobber list for your inline assembly to `"cc, memory"` should prevent the compiler from reordering functions.